# Apache Mesos: where is zkClient.sh?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-zookeeper, mesos

I am on Ubuntu.

I am trying to follow the tutorial "Starting Mesos", on https://mesosphere.com/downloads/

I can't find `zkClient.sh` on my machine. `locate zkClient.sh` returns nothing.

Any help?

---

### Information of my configuration:

1) I have installed and configured zookeeper, with the "standalone configuration" in conf/zoo.cfg:

```
tickTime=2000   
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper  
clientPort=2181
```

2) I have installed Apache Mesos through the *.deb file from the mesosphere repository

3) I have launched zookeper using

```
sudo /usr/share/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start
```

then each process using

```
service mesos-slave start   # (sudo if needed)  
service mesos-master start  # (sudo if needed)
```

`ps aux | grep mesos` returns me informations that seem to indicate that both the zookeer server and client are up:

```
root     29190  0.2  0.1 1490628 22460 ?       Ssl  11:31   0:00 /usr/sbin/mesos-master --zk=zk://localhost:2181/mesos --port=5050 --log_dir=/var/log/mesos --quorum=1 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos
root     29200  0.0  0.0  11360   604 ?        S    11:31   0:00 logger -p user.info -t mesos-master[29190]
root     29201  0.0  0.0  11360   708 ?        S    11:31   0:00 logger -p user.err -t mesos-master[29190]
root     29229  0.1  0.1 947316 18332 ?        Ssl  11:31   0:00 /usr/sbin/mesos-slave --master=zk://localhost:2181/mesos --log_dir=/var/log/mesos --launcher=posix
root     29237  0.0  0.0  11360   600 ?        S    11:31   0:00 logger -p user.info -t mesos-slave[29229]
root     29238  0.0  0.0  11360   712 ?        S    11:31   0:00 logger -p user.err -t mesos-slave[29229]
john   29260  0.0  0.0  13588   940 pts/3    R+   11:32   0:00 grep --color=auto mesos
```

But then the tutorial says "Once the Master(s) are started, use ZooKeeper to verify that you have the correct configuration: Launch the ZooKeeper client with zkClient.sh"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be zkCli.sh and you can find it at  /usr/share/zookeeper/bin/zkCli.sh.
You can launch it as follows

```
sudo /usr/share/zookeeper/bin/zkCli.sh -server localhost:2181
```

Comment: You can remove `-server localhost:2181` parameter in this situation because it is the default value.